# how to display a value in div when click a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i'm still new to this. . i want the value to display in a div that i already defined in css when i click a button. but the only thing that come out is the button. i just can't get the right result that i wanthere's what i've done.

```
<?php
var $val=001;
function increase(){
    echo "<div id='display' >$val++</div>" ;
}

?>
<body>
<div id="display"> 
<button type="button" onclick="increse()">click me!!</button>
</div>
</body>


---------------------my #display in css-------------
.display{
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
background-color:#CECECE;
}
```

please help. or maybe refer me to something useful. thank you :)

Comment: javascript can't call php functions.  Also, you typoed your function name.

Comment: you are mixing up javascript and PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
<div id="display"> 
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">click me!!</button>
</div>
</body>
```

you should use javascript with this
    `

```
function increase()
{
    var val=001;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=val++;
}
</script>`
```

if you want to do this in php:

```
<body>
<div id="display"> 
<button type="button" onclick="<?php increase(); ?>">click me!!</button>
</div>
</body>
```

but this will not give the wanted results as this will append another div with same id display

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="likes">13</div>
<button class="btn">Increment</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var num = parseInt($('.likes').text());
  $('.likes').text(num+1);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/jg5GA/47/)**

Now you can modify it according to your needs

Comment: parseInt($('.likes').text());-----> '.likes' is referring to what?? a value?

Comment: `.likes` is class of a div .. `$(.likes.text());` is to get a value